# Not proper in column when importing csv file into datagridview

Tags: sql, excel, vb.net, csv, datagridview

I have problem when importing csv file into datagridview. It is not in proper column in only add column.

Here is the code:

```
 Try
        Dim conn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim ds As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim comm As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim path As String = filepath

        conn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + "; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        comm = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [WSC2017_TP09_M2_Schedules_V12_a$]", conn)

        ds = New System.Data.DataSet
        comm.Fill(ds)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

here are some images...

It is supposed to be here:
[image: it is supposed to be here;]
But it goes here:
[image: but it goes here.]

Comment: Your DataGridView has probably a DataPropertyName already set and the Fields coming from DataSource don't match.

Comment: What happens if you specify the columns in the order you want them instead of using `*`?

Comment: You are probably defining your columns at design time instead of letting the `DataSource` define them at run time. If you are going to do it that way, then you need to also set each column's `DataPropertyName`.

Comment: How to use DataPropertyName?

Comment: Don't add column manually in your dgvw, just let the datagridview load the columns from the datasource